# Difference between .getAttribute("value") & just .value

Tags: javascript

I have seen two types of usage

```
var name = document.getElementById("username").value;
```

or

```
var name = document.getElementById("username").getAttribute("value");
```

Likewise for setAttribute also. I have a form where setAttribute works for one of the fields (it's a hidden field) and doesn't work for another field (not hidden) & I have to use

```
document.getElementById("username").value = "something"
```

to set the field

By doesn't work, I mean the field doesn't get set when I use setAttribute. It retains it's original value.

So what's the different between these 2 ways? Is there a rule on when one is supposed to use one way & when another?

Comment: This link given by @thesystem exactly answers this